# MYSQL Duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values into a table in MYSQL, the table has a column which should be unique,so that column always will have different values.

I tried putting `UNIQUE` for the coloumn but it did not work,
Also tried putting that column as `PRIMARY KEY` and insert `IGNORE INTO` command it did not work (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm)

My intention is to put `phonenumber` column unique so every value in this column is different. if the newly inserting value is not unique it should skip wihout giving error.

My code to Create table:

```
  public function create_member_table($table)
 {
$this->sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table ( id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                                    phonenumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                                    country VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                                    profession VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
                                    profilepic VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
                                    smskey VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                    status INT NOT NULL,
                                    reg_date_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
                                    UNIQUE (id,phonenumber))
                                    PARTITION BY HASH(id)
                                    PARTITIONS 1023;";
$this->tb = mysqli_query($this->ret,$this->sql);
if(!$this->tb){
  echo "Table not created<br>";

}
else{
  echo "Table created<br>";

}
```

Insert table:

```
  public function table_member_insert($table,$phonenumber="",$username="",$country="",$profession="",$profilepic="0",$smskey="",$status="") {

   $this->sql = "INSERT INTO $table
                  (username,phonenumber,country,profession,profilepic,smskey,status,reg_date_time)
                  VALUES
                  ('$username','$phonenumber','$country','$profession','$profilepic','$smskey','$status',now());";

                  $this->tb = mysqli_query($this->ret,$this->sql);
                  if(!$this->tb){
                    echo "values not inserted<br>";

                  }
                  else{
                    echo "values inserted<br>";
                  } }
```

Comment: Isn't there an answer for your question? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you defined the **combination** of id and phonenumber fields as unique. Since your id field is defined as auto_increment, it will be unique on its own, therefore any combination with phonenumber field will also be unique.

You need to define the phonenumber field **alone** as unique. After that you can use insert ignore to insert a new record with an existing phone number without raisin an error. However, pls note that in case of a match, the unique index will prevent the entire record from being inserted.

Comment: Shadow is correct -- you are defining a composite unique index.  In addition, to change from your composite to `UNIQUE(phonenumber)`, you'll have to remove your user-defined `PARTITION` since partitions are organized by unique indices.

Comment: I removed `id` and tried. table not at all getting created. Do I have to remove `PARTITIONS` too?

Comment: Check the error message MySQL provided you with and act on it. Pls do not ask us to **guess** error messages when you are readily provided with them. Pls also read @Cam 's comment as well.